# Please enable MathJax mhchem extension on Chemistry.SE

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

The newly launched Chemistry.SE (currently in private beta) would greatly benefit from having MathJax's **mhchem** extension enabled. I believe it's very straightforward, as it's part of the standard MathJax 2.0, which SE uses. It only requires site-wide activation.

See the [relevant discussion](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13/30) on Chemistry’s meta.

[Here is the other relevant discussion (includes shiny links to instructions)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/enable-mhchem-mathjax-extension)

Comment: I *love* shiny links.

Comment: I dunno if this is on-topic here, though. You can get attention, but this is site-specific and ought to stay there. The SE team mopes around private betas anyway, so they'll see it soon enough. Otherwise, the pro-tems will bring it to the attention of SE. I'm voting to close, even though I sorely want to see this implemented. :(

Comment: The appropriate place for this request is on meta.chemistry.  Since there is already a post there, I'm just closing this instead of migrating.